# Можно ли в кострукторе класса проверить некое условие и сразу запустить деструктор, если условие не удовлетворяет?

Tags: c++

Можно ли в конструкторе класса проверить некое условие и сразу запустить деструктор, если условие не удовлетворяется?
Или же придется бросать исключение?

Comment: А какой в этом будет смысл? Каким образом внешний код сможет узнать, что конструкция объекта завершилась безуспешно? На основе чего?

Comment: Мне кажется, что для этой задачи существуют "статические" методы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И что вы хотите получить? Отсутствие объекта? Но если объект начал создаваться - то на выходе должен либо быть корректный объект, либо исключение.

Вы можете, скажем, освободить память - выполняя действия деструктора, но все равно если нет исключения - в результате должен быть создан валидный объект...

Вы в принципе можете вызвать деструктор

```
class String
{
public:
    String(const char * s);
    ~String();
private:
    char * s;
};

String::String(const char * x)
{
    s = new char[strlen(x)+1];
    strcpy(s,x);
    if (1 /*в строке - маты :)*/)
    {
        this->~String();
        s = nullptr;
    }
}

String::~String()
{
    delete[] s;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    String s("hello");
}
```

Только объект-то все равно будет создан. Как и при динамическом создании - вызвав `new`, вы уже выделяете память. Если конструктор не сгенерирует исключение - что окажется в этой памяти?

Comment: Ясненько, значит лучше таки сделать выброс исключения. Изначальная задумка была создать "необязательный объект", который может создаться, а может и нет, и в нужном месте просто проверить его наличие или отсутствие

Comment: Если нужен "необязательный объект" - создайте функцию, которая будет его создавать, если нужно. А вызывать деструктор в конструкторе... Оно то можно, но не стоит. В примере @Harry - грубая ошибка - двойной вызов деструктора. А это почти всегда выстрел в ногу

Comment: @KoVadim В данном случае показано, как делать нельзя :), но опять же - в силу присваивания `s = nullptr;` это вполне нормальный вызов. В свое время, кстати, достаточное распространение имела идиома вызова деструктора в операторе присваивания с последующим конструированием.

Comment: если так делать нельзя - то об этом пишут "БОЛЬШИМИ КРАСНЫМИ БУКВАМИ". Код, который вызвал подобный деструктор должен как то догадаться, что объект полуразрушенный.

Comment: Как я понимаю, такой объект должен быть сугубо динамическим - как иначе определить "несуществующий" статический объект? Тогда проще определять указатель - нулевой - ненулевой. А еще проще и понятнее - `bool` переменную :) Сам объект имеет смысл, если нужна еще какая-то информация о чем-то там, получаемая из объекта. Тогда его надо создавать в любом случае. И еще - представим, что вы хотите так сделать с объектом типа `int`. Как вы себе представляете его несуществование?...

Comment: @KoVadim Еще раз и медленно :) - вы прочли мой ответ? Что можно вызвать деструктор (и его таки МОЖНО вызывать, язык не запрещает), но это занятие бессмысленное. Я показал, что вызов деструктора все равно оставляет объект созданным - что и было ответом на заданный вопрос, что этот метод просто не даст никакого эффекта. Второй вопрос, поднятый вами - можно ли явно вызывать деструктор - на него я отвечаю: да, можно, при полном понимании, что вы делаете. Впрочем, условие полного понимания - такое же, как и для вызова любого другого метода :), так что красных букв не требует.

Comment: да, я прочитал. Но ответ выглядит как будто это нельзя, но если сильно хочется то можно и ничего плохого не будет.  И не нужно "медленно". **"вы хотите так сделать с объектом типа int"** - вставлю в shared_ptr/scope_ptr (по потребностям).

Comment: @KoVadim 1. Это будет полный завершенный объект интеллектуального указателя, что не удовлетворяет поставленному условию. 2. Я уже это писал - *Как я понимаю, такой объект должен быть сугубо динамическим - как иначе определить "несуществующий" статический объект?* - и написал, что тогда нет смысла заморачиваться с каким-то объектом, достаточно булева флага.